# Waiting for animations in a SetInterval gameloop

Tags: javascript, setinterval

So my problem is I want to insert a custom animation but I don't want to ruin my gameloop.

My initial gameloop is stated here:

```
function init(){

      if(!gameOver){
        if(resetInterval>-1) clearInterval(resetInterval);
        createBlock();
        resetInterval = setInterval(moveDownCheck,gameSpeed);
      }
    }
```

My game is a tetris like game except instead of dropping tetriminos, I drop 2x1 blocks of different color. The `moveDownCheck` method checks if there are any blocks under my 2x1 block and then drops it by 1 row. This works fine until I have a block hanging without a block underneath since the 2x1 blocks are connected. I want to insert a drop animation that would take about a second and drop the hanging block by the same `gameSpeed` increment.
Here is my attempt that doesn't work:

```
function moveFallingDown(){
      fbDownFlag = false;
      clearInterval(resetInterval);
      fbInterval = setInterval(function(){
        fallingBlock.row++;
        console.log("Dropped One Row");
        },gameSpeed);
      while(landscape[fallingBlock.row+1][fallingBlock.col]==0){
        console.log("Waiting to Drop Falling Block");
      }
      clearInterval(fbInterval);
      resetInterval = setInterval(moveDownCheck,gameSpeed);
}
```

Here I am attempting to wait for the `function(){fallingBlock.row++;}`, but my game just crashes and in the console `"Dropped One Row"` yet `"Waiting to Drop Falling Block"` will display thousands of times.
I guess I shouldn't be using a while loop here, but the only other solution I can think of would be a complete rework of my design, or nested setInterval methods which would just make my head hurt too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with a while loop, you need to use a recursive function. `window.setTimeout` would work, however this seems like a good use case for `requestAnimationFrame`. Check it out here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame

You can use that to call your `moveFallingDown` method, and check how long has passed since the last animation frame to move your animation the right amount according to the game speed, by using the high precision timestamp passed to the requestAnimationFrame callback.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out Adrien, but I'm just a little confused as to how this would help me out. Does `requestAnimationFrame` wait until the callback function is finished before it continues on?

Comment: `requestAnimationFrame` calls your callback function every time the browser is going to repaint the screen, which happens roughly 60 times per second. It passes your function a high res timestamp of when exactly that repaint will occur. So the callback function can use that timestamp to determine how much time has passed since the last time it was called, and based on the difference, how much to animate. Then it should decide whether to call `requestAnimationFrame` again to keep the process going.

Answer (score 0):

@Adrien Delessert's advice is correct but I'll just add that you're definitely confusing setTimeout and setInterval.

First of all you don't need a while loop.

setInterval IS a loop. So, if you wanted to use it you'd need to wrap (basically) the whole game in a method that moves the game forward (whatever that means) and pass that to setInterval.

However, what you're doing (and this is actually not a terrible approach) is to use it as a means to animate specific things. In that case you should have a recursive(ish) function that keeps calling setTimeout when it's done, if the conditions for another round of animation are met.

I haven't ever used requestAnimationFrame, but that does sound like a much more elegant approach to the problem.

The reason it's better is that it leverages the browser's own refresh timer (about 60 times per second) and will slot your animation frames in along with its own refresh.

So yes, you will listen for that callback and then react to it as necessary. If 60x per second is too fast, you'll need to put in a % based counter for how many of those frames you wish to actually react to.